# Start a process within a HttpSession and hand it over to another "owner" before session expires?

Tags: java, session, runtime.exec

I (am trying) to develop a web application system, which handles user requests and calculations and passes them to (tailor-made) executables on the server via extending Threads and Runtime.exec() (on Linux and/or Windows). These calculations could be very time consuming and could exceed the duration of HttpSession. If this happens, and the session expires, the thread/process also dies along with the HttpSession (right?).

My question: is there a way to start a process within a session and handover it to a session independent process, for example?

It doesn't matter if I can't trace the process ID, I only search a way to start processes on the webserver and let them running, even if the user's session expires.

I'm thankful for any ideas and hints!

Comment: The session has nothing to do with external processes, but locking the execution of the servlet for a long time is a **terrible** approach; you need to use some kind of asynchronous message system, like a shared DB or pipes of some kind.

Comment: I don't think Coolspot is suggesting that and is actually asking how to avoid that.

Comment: maybe you can use a poll in your page calling the server every N seconds or minutes asking if the process is done, so your session won't expire

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Yes, but it's totallay okay/desired, that the httpsession can expire. The user could for example start a 2-day job, logs out and come back after three days, while the job was done at the background.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Job Scheduling libray like [Quartz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-quartz/), so your Jobs doesn't depend at all of HttpSession

Comment: Thank you, looks interesting on the first sight! I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend starting processes via `Runtime.exec` or creating new threads from inside the web server.  While it is often technically possible, it's not a good idea.  Basically, the threads that you're starting would not be under the web containers control (which has a number of worker threads to handle your requests).  By starting your own threads, the web server cannot manage its own load anymore and you might end up with a whole host of unintended consequences.

What I would do is the following:

- When the request for a new calculation comes in, I'd create a unique ID and store that in a DB as "calculation pending" with the user id.
- Then I would package up the data for the request and put it on a JMS queue to be scheduled for calculation.
- Your web container can return that ID to the web browser.
- The web browser can use the ID to go back to the web server with "Is calculation `ID` done yet?"  The server can check the database and see whether the status is still "pending".
- On your web-page you could display some "processing..." message and a progress bar which would periodically refresh and check whether the calculation is still progressing (say a refresh every 10 seconds).  That would keep your HttpSession alive (though that's not necessary as the user could log in again and check the ID or if you've stored the username in the DB record could see all of the user's "pending" calculations).
- The calculation would be carried out by a separate application, which basically listens to incoming messages on the JMS/MQ queue and then creates a new thread.  Now this can be on the same machine or a different machine (and using JMS allows you the flexibility to use the JMS configuration, or multiple "worker" machines listening to JMS messages to carry out the calculations.
- Once the calculation is finished, the "worker" would package the result and send a JMS response message (including the `ID`).
- Back on your server you can then have a message driven bean which would insert the results into the database and change the status of the DB to "finished" and makes the results available.
- Now when the web page refreshes, because the results are available, you can redirect to a results page (and get the results from the database).

Advantages of using JMS:

- The messages can be persisted, resent if there is a problem.
- Java EE spec compliant

Advantages of storing calculation results in the DB:

- Look at historical calculations
- If the calculation is idempotent you could look up the result from previous calculations.

Hope that helps.